# Ist das eine indirekte Frage?

Tags: interrogative

Heißt es:

> Ich würde gerne wissen, ob ich das Motivationsschreiben an Sie adressieren soll.

oder

> Ich würde gerne wissen, ob ich das Motivationsschreiben an Sie adressieren soll?

Ich tue mich schwer damit das herauszufinden.

Comment: Was ist die Frage nun? Welche Schreibweise besser ist? Oder ob der Satz grammatisch gesehen eine indirekte Frage ist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Unterschied zwischen deinen beiden Beispielsätzen ist - wie der aufmerksame Leser nach einigem Suchen sieht - nur das Fragezeichen.

Beide Varianten sind möglich.

Die Form mit Punkt ist vielleicht näher an der grammatischen Logik, denn "Ich würde gerne wissen..." ist ja eine Aussage, keine Frage, und ein Aussagesatz schließt mit einem Punkt.

Die Form mit dem Fragezeichen wirkt vielleicht etwas altertümlicher, aber auch etwas höflicher. Das Fragezeichen regt bei lautem Lesen dazu an, am Satzende die Stimme zu heben, was im Deutschen das akustische Signal für eine Frage ist. Dadurch wird deutlich, dass der Satz - höflich - als Frage und nicht etwa - fordernd - als Feststellung gemeint ist.

Comment: Für mich ähnlich, wobei eigentlich nur der zweite Satz (sprechakttheoretisch) klar als Frage funktioniert; er hat einen - wie gesagt zurückhaltenden - Aufforderungscharakter, nämlich die Bitte um Antwort. Der erste Satz liest sich für mich ein wenig wie 'ich würde das gerne mal wissen ...', ein Informationswunsch. Praktisch ist klar, was gemeint ist, mir erscheint 1 etwas unpersönlicher.